# Split test coverage for front and backend in VSTS

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, azure-devops, code-coverage

In my repository I have 2 folders:

```
- backend/
- frontend/
```

Backend contains xUnit and Specflow based tests for .NET Core api. Frontend in Typescript contains Jasmine tests (`ng test`).

In my build pipeline I do:

- build backend
- launch unit tests for backend (vsTest task)
- launch integration tests for backend (vsTest task)
- build frontend
- launch tests for frontend (`ng test`???)

Is there any chance to do this:

- prepare combined coverage report for all backend tests and all frontend tests. Visualize these 2 reports and coverage % in the build result. Setup coverage % gate to fail if it less than X% (separately for back/front)
- to combine all coverage reports and implement the same gate, but for both back/front?

Comment: What test result format does ng test generate?

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend against having required code coverage percentages. Code coverage is **not** an indication of quality, it is simply an indication of what is or is not being touched by tests. It gives no assurance that the tests are valuable or testing the correct things. It is a tool for showing developers which sections of code are untouched by tests, nothing more. Using it as a quality gate is only going to result in poor tests intended to push the percentage up to meet the bar.

Comment: @DanielMann I fully agree with you. We have the testing strategy with the defined levels and approaches of testing. This is only a part of the scope which helps to identify at least something what can be identified automatically..

Answer (score 0):

No, the test coverage results can’t be splatted show in Code Coverage section of build/release summary.

You can add the coverage result to build/release summary through [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path).

On the other hand, there isn’t the feature to fail task per to the coverage % gate in VSTS, you need to analysis the coverage results manually (e.g. Through powershell)